# My Ford Escort ZX2 not starting

Tags: ford, starting, escort

Ford Escort ZX2

I go to turn my car on. I have power, but it will not start. No clicking. Took starter off, it was bad. Put it back on. Also, took a new battery, put in my car from truck. Still same thing. What could be my problem?

Comment: Question is very unclear ... can you slow down a bit and explain in detail since there are thousands of things associated with car not staring

Comment: It doesn't click

Comment: It has power inside car but after replacing starter still it's not starting

Comment: If I may ask, please use punctuation in your questions ... sure makes it a *lot* easier to read and understand what you are trying to say. You *did* replace the starter?

Comment: What year is your Escort?

Comment: Yes... I did still not turning over at all. It's a 2001

Comment: It does have power but will not turn over

Comment: There should be two main posts on your starter solenoid which have wires attached to them. The main one getting power from the battery. The other is the energizer from the ignition switch. Test the starter by jumping these two posts with a screwdriver (briefly), to see if the engine will turn over. If this works, this is likely a problem with the ignition switch or starting mechanism controlled by the ignition switch. Ensure you are only touching the two posts with the screwdriver or sparks will ensue.

Answer (score 1):

There should be two main posts on your starter solenoid which have wires attached to them. The main one getting power from the battery. The other is the energizer from the ignition switch. Test the starter by jumping these two posts with a screwdriver (briefly), to see if the engine will turn over. If this works, this is likely a problem with the ignition switch or starting mechanism controlled by the ignition switch. Ensure you are only touching the two posts with the screwdriver or sparks will ensue.